# Number of concurrent requests a server can handle

Tags: tcp, server, concurrency

In the book "Computer Networking - A Top Down Approach", I just studied that, TCP sockets are uniquely identified by four parameters:

1. Sender's IP address
2. Sender's port number
3. Receiver's IP address
4. Receiver's port number

In the case of server, we know that the server's IP address and the port number is fixed. Clients' IP addresses and the port numbers will obviously vary. In case of new request, the server will open a new thread (to open a new TCP socket) to handle that request.

My question is that, is there any calculation we can perform to calculate maximum number of clients a single server machine can handle?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi，it's a good question.

First, if one thread handles one connection, then the limitation of x86 computer will be really low. It will be something like 1000 for every process since the virtual memory is limited as 4GB. For x64, it will be relatively higher. But the switch between threads is not we want to see.

So, we use a thread to process lots of connections, that is I/O multiplexing.

What's more, this still has a limitation, we call it [C10K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem) and [C10M](http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/5/13/the-secret-to-10-million-concurrent-connections-the-kernel-i.html), and we solve these probolems by non-blocking I/O multiplexing like epoll or IOCP, and the DPDK is useful to solve C10M.

If you want to reach a higher connection number, then we use distributed systems instead only one server.

It's a long story of the limitation of server, and I think you can learn much from them.